# How to navigate through a react native app without stacks

Tags: react-native

I wanted to know how I can navigate through my react native app without using tab or stack navigation. I would like to create a button and onPress navigate directly to that page. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drawer to try and achieve the same functionality as createDrawerNavigator. It seems pretty straightforward. However, when in my DrawerScreen.js when I try and click the button to navigate I get the error that was mentioned previously.

I did try something like:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
    <Text> Home </Text> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

however, I got errors such as `"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')"`.

Here is my code-

```
//file - App.js

import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import {createStackNavigator} from  'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './src/LoginScreen/LoginScreen.js';

import HomeScreen from './src/HomeScreen/HomeScreen.js';

import SignUpScreen from './src/SignUpScreen/SignUpScreen.js';

import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
    <AppStackNavigtor/>
    );
  }
}

const AppStackNavigtor = createStackNavigator ({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  SignUp: SignUpScreen,
  Home: HomeScreen,
})

// file - DrawerScreen.js


import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StackNavigator} from 'react-native';

import HomeScreen from '../HomeScreen/HomeScreen';

import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer';

import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class DrawerScreen extends React.Component {
render () {
  return (

    <TouchableOpacity style = {{top: 100}} 
    onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}>
    <Text> Home </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    );
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({

})
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've done so far. Your code is not wrong, but the class where you use it is probably not in a navigator

Comment: @Poptocrack just did an update

Comment: Code is Really hard to read, please take time to format it

Comment: Where do you use `createDrawerNavigator`? You import it but don't use it or not showing us where you use it!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should wrap your component with `withNavigation` in order to be able to use `this.props.navigation` as documented here [withNavigation()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav).

First import withNavigation from react-navigation and export `DrawerScreen` as follows:

```
export default withNavigation(DrawerScreen)
```

Answer (score -2):

You are declaring you navigator with:

```
const AppStackNavigtor = createStackNavigator ({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  SignUp: SignUpScreen,
  Home: HomeScreen, // here you declare Home from HomeScreen class
})
```

Your navigation should be:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
```

You can put HomeScreen in the navigate function is you declare your navigator like so:

```
const AppStackNavigtor = createStackNavigator ({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  SignUp: SignUpScreen,
  HomeScreen: HomeScreen, // put this line or...
  HomeScreen, // or this one
})
```

Comment: His problem come from `this.props.navigation`